# Question on ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Try to find the general solution for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=3y^{2/3}$

Your answer will probably be $y=(x+C)^3$.

Observe $y=0$ is also a solution and it cannot be expressed as $y=（x+C）^3$ for any value of $C$.

How do you account for this? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: You can glue solutions together, $(x-c)^3$ for $x < c$, $0$ for $c < x < b$, $(x-b)^3$ for $x > b$. The function $f(y) = 3 y^{2/3}$ is not Lipschitz continuous at $0$.

Comment: but where is the minus from????

Comment: During separation of variables you need to assume $y\ne 0$ to be able to divide.  At that point you investigate $y=0$ as a solution. There is no uniqueness of solution for this equation as $\partial f \over \partial y$ is not continuous at $y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the nice comments by Daniel and Maesumi, we can actually calculate the Lipschitz Condition and check that it is not satisfied. That is a good exercise to do!

However, we can also look at a direction field plot as follows.

[image]

From the direction fields, we can see that the solution can go in two different directions from an initial condition.

If we take your example $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=3y^{2/3}$ with an initial condition $y(0) = 0$, we have:

$$y(x) = 0 ~\text{or}~ y(x) = x^3$$

If we take $y(0) = 1$, we get:

- $y(x) = (x+1)^3$, or
- $y(x) = x^3-3 (-1)^{1/3} x^2+3 (-1)^{2/3} x+1$, or
- $y(x) = x^3+3 (-1)^{2/3} x^2-3 (-1)^{1/3} x+1$.

If we solve the general system as you show it, we have:

$$y(x) = \dfrac{1}{27} (27 c_1 x^2+9 c_1^2 x+c_1^3+27 x^3)$$

Lavrentieff constructed a more dramatic example, which consisted in a continuous function on a rectangle such that uniqueness fails at every initial condition $(x_0, y_0)$ in the rectangle’s interior. See: M. Lavrentieff, Sur une equation differentielle du premier ordre, Math. Z. 23 (1925) 197–209.

Later, in 1963, Hartman published a simpler example of that type with a function deﬁned on the whole plane. See: P. Hartman, A differential equation with non-unique solutions, this MONTHLY 70 (1963) 255–259.

Comment: Needs a TU! $+1$

Answer (score 0):

According to Deniel Fischer's hint $f(x) = 3y^{\frac{2}{3}}$ does not satisfy Lipschitz,s condition in some nbd of $(0,0)$. So the differential equation does not have unique solution. Even in this case one may get infinitely many solutions.